# Hive Action in Oozie 3.1.3

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I am a newbie to Hive and Oozie. I am trying to run a Hive script through Oozie.
This is the error I got.

> Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is     strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'hive'.

Here is my workflow.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="temp-hive">
  <start to="hive-ex"/>
  <action name="hive-ex">
  <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
  <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
  <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
  <configuration>
  <property>
  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
  <value>default</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
   <value>/home/hduser/hive/conf/hive-site.xml</value>
  </property>
  </configuration>
  <script>ooziequery.q</script>
  </hive>
  <ok to="end"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
  </action>
  <kill name="fail">
  <message>Hive script failed!!</message>
  </kill>
  <end name="end"/>
  </workflow-app>
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the oozie:workflow and hive-action versions.

In my case, I use CDH4.3 distribution and I put the following versions:

0.4 for oozie workflow and 0.2 for hive action

```
<workflow-app name="test-hive" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
<start to="hive-request"/>
<action name="hive-request">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node> 
    <job-xml>conf/hive-site.xml</job-xml>
        <script>lib/script.sql</script>
    </hive>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
<!-- Fail bloc, redirect every action here when an error occurs-->
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```